'such that' - how to pronounce and what is their function?

The effect on our blood chemistry is such that it produces physical changes in our entire body.

Do I have to make a pause after such: such / pause / that? (in this case such is subject to 'is'.
Or do I have to say with no pause: such that? (in this case 'such' is felt like a 'dummy' to a non-native speaker of English like me.
I would appreciate your help in advance.

A pause after "such" is natural there. It is complemented by a declarative content clause.   But "is such that it" could be eliminated from the sentence.

'such' describes or modifies 'that clause'? What's the role of such here?

"such" is predicated of "the effect":  "The effect is such" .  And "such" is complemented by the content clause, which supplies the content for "such".

What about 'such as' instead of 'such that' for my example?

"such as" introduces examples, normally noun phrases.  It would be ungrammatical here when followed by "it produces ..."

You can understand such to mean roughly “the type.”

The temperature was such that the water in the birdbath froze means pretty much, “The temperature was the type that causes water to freeze.”
People such as him should not be trusted means pretty much, “People of his type should not be trusted.”
Such things make me wonder means pretty much, “Things of that type make me wonder.”

I would not pause at all after speaking the word such.

Thx Paul. You would not pause at all after even 'such that+ subject+verb construction'?

No, not at all.

The 'such' in 'such that' has a feel of an intensifier? Like 'such a good boy'?

No. That’s a perfectly reasonable idea, but that kind of intensification in constructions like Your room is such a mess! doesn’t happen in such that clauses. By the way, even those intensifiers have some of that type meaning: such a good boy means something like, “of the very best type of boy.”

Can I ask why you used 'but' conjunction after 'That's perfectly reasonable idea,'? I think 'so' or 'and' would be appropriate. And 'of the very best type of boy' is a noun phrase or adjectival phrase? The 'of' in "of the very best type" is confusing. Can I use "of importance of fact" as noun phrase to mean "important fact"?

"of the supalative+1st noun of 2nd noun" is a formula to mean a 2nd noun? It's really interesting.

It’s a reasonable idea to hypothesize but it doesn’t actually hold.

He is such a good boy can be paraphrased by He is an example of the very best type of boy.



The effect on our blood chemistry is such that it produces physical changes in our entire body.



My piano playing was such that it impressed the judges.

In the above sentences, "such that" can be understood as "in a way that".
The phrase "such that" is frequently encountered in mathematics, where it typically means "for which" or "in which" or "satisfying".
There should absolutely be no pause between "such" and "that".
P.S. More succinctly:

The effect on our blood chemistry induces physical changes throughout the body.

However, your intended meaning is more likely something like

The effect is biochemical, inducing physical changes throughout the body.
The effect is biochemical: it induces physical changes throughout the body.


Your 'in a way that' is very close to 'such that' in both terms of construction and meaning. By the way, am I correct to use "in both terms of" instead of "in terms of" since I have not seen the expression "in both terms of": it's my creature.

@gomadeng By the way, am I correct to use "in both terms of"?  Correction: Your 'in a way that' is very close to 'such that' in terms of both construction and meaning (better) or Your 'in a way that' is very close to 'such that' both in terms of construction and in terms of meaning.   By the way, I've just added a postscript to the answer above.

If there is a prior description of another (primary) effect on our blood chemistry,
such would refer to it.  We'd have a pause, and I'd also add a comma.  The
physical changes in our entire body is then considered a result of that effect.
If there's no mention of
such primary effect, we don't pause.  There's also no comma.

Thx for your answer. If there is no mention of such primary effect, you say 'such that' is like a chunk. Then you 'such' describes or modifies 'that clause'? What's the role of 'such' here?

"is" is the important factor here, not previous mention. "The effect is such, that ..." versus "He gave the door a kick, such that it ..."

@gomadeng, Google considers
such that a phrase meaning
to the extent that.

Yeah, 'to the extent that' is similar one. My asking is related with 'such / pause / that and the role of such.

I now think the such is a chunk with that though a pause may be natural. It's like a correlating conjunction so I think the 'that' can not be omitted.
